# How to prepare any repository to host actual website to the outside world?

Tags: github-pages

I was following a video in which he went to settings and there he got 'github pages' heading where he got 'Launch automatic page generator' button but I didnot get any 'github pages' heading. But at left side i saw a pages option but there is no such button. How can i create it.

I open that pages option from where i select 'main' in branch and somehow got my link for website. But he was getting 2 branches option 'main and gh-pages' and i was only getting 1 branch 'main'. I want to change layout for my website and get that second branch which emerges after publishing website.